# Python REST API call equivalent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I've been recently trying to communicate with the UniProt API. As I am starting with Node.js, I have some initial problems, namely:

I am trying to conver this python request:

```
import urllib,urllib2

url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/'

params = {
'from':'ACC',
'to':'P_REFSEQ_AC',
'format':'tab',
'query':'P13368 P20806 Q9UM73 P97793 Q17192'
}

data = urllib.urlencode(params)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
contact = "" # Please set your email address here to help us debug in case of problems.
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Python %s' % contact)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
page = response.read(200000)
```

To node.js.

My attempt:

```
var params = {
'from':'ACC',
'to':'P_REFSEQ_AC',
'format':'json',
'query':'P13368 P20806 Q9UM73 P97793 Q17192'
}



var post_data = querystring.stringify(params);
var url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/'

var options = {
uri: url,
qs: post_data,
method: 'POST'
};

urllib.request(options, function (err, data, res) {
if (err) {
    throw err; // you need to handle error
}
console.log(data.toString())

cb("test") // this doesnt currently matter
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) can help you achieve what you are trying.

```
npm i node-rest-client --save
```

I believe you have a starter project for nodejs which contains package.json.

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();

var args = {
    data: {
        'from': 'ACC',
        'to': 'P_REFSEQ_AC',
        'format': 'json',
        'query': 'P13368 P20806 Q9UM73 P97793 Q17192'
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"//use the header that you need
    }
};

client.post("http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/", args, function(data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object 
    console.log(data);
    // raw response 
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I see the "response" object is quite large. So If I understand correctly, the returned data is located there?

Comment: can you share whats in the data?. Response is raw

Comment: Yes, the data looks like a giant blob of HTML.

Comment: @sdgawerzswer, ahh okay . I think the problem is that api is sending the html as the response. If you try the post in postman, it is giving the html as well.

Comment: Okay, am I supposed to parse the HTML directly then?

Comment: what are you doing with your python code with the response that you are getting from your python api

Comment: Nothing really, I am trying to do this in node. The aim is to obtain mappings,a.k.a tab separated entries, which will be further processed.

Comment: You are trying to get back a JSON response but that is not acceptable. We send back the default HTML response instead. We support xml, txt, tab, rdf in turtle, rdf/xml and in very early beta jsonld.

Comment: @sdgawerzswer the mappings should be done from the server side to which you are requesting. The code you have written in python is what i have written in nodejs and that is what you are asking in the question. Please create a new thread for whatever confusion you have